# While accessing google speech api, I am receiving 403 forbidden from server

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-api-java-client, google-speech-api

I understand that this questions is discussed around 4-5 times but none of the solutions posted had helped me.

I created google developer account and enabled Google speech api, also registered project and have generated API_KEY. I am using JARVIS (on Google speech v2) to synthesize and recognize speech on my Java program.

The server always responds with 403 (forbidden) when querying the URL. I understand that it is saying I am not authorized. I even enabled billing to sort it out, but no luck.

```
Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://www.google.com/speech-api/v2/recognize?output=json&lang=en-us&key=MY_KEY?client=chromium&output=json&lang=en-US&maxresults=4
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.darkprograms.speech.recognizer.Recognizer.rawRequest(Recognizer.java:455)
    at com.darkprograms.speech.recognizer.Recognizer.getRecognizedDataForFlac(Recognizer.java:280)
    at com.darkprograms.speech.main.ArtificialIntelligenceErrorDetection.speechToTextLogic(ArtificialIntelligenceErrorDetection.java:80)
    at com.darkprograms.speech.main.ArtificialIntelligenceErrorDetection.listenAlexa(ArtificialIntelligenceErrorDetection.java:43)
    at com.darkprograms.speech.main.VoiceServer$voiceHandler.handle(VoiceServer.java:60)
```

Please note, I am not using project ID generated by google. I think there is some missing link here. However, requesting your wise thoughts in this regards.

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: How does the API you want to use, say you need to pass in your credentials?

Answer (score 0):

[Method: speech.recognize](https://cloud.google.com/speech/reference/rest/v1/speech/recognize)

> Requires the following OAuth scope:
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform For more information,
>   see the [Auth Guide](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication).

API key is used for accessing Public apis.  You will need to create Oauth2 credentials and authenticate in order to access this api.

```
https://www.google.com/speech-api/v2/recognize?output=json&lang=en-us&access_token=accessTokenfromAuth&client=chromium&output=json&lang=en-US&maxresults=4
```

Google has a number of official samples that may be of help.  [Here](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/samples)